# Nginx - 403 from period in directory name?

Tags: nginx, vite

Bashing my head against the wall here, hopefully someone can help!

I'm trying to serve a Vite app locally behind Nginx. What I'm noticing is the files are served from node_modules in a directory named .vite for HMR. Any file requested from this directory results in a 403. I'm not sure if it's due to the dot in the directory or what.

Example (403):

```
https://dev.localhost/my-project-name/node_modules/.vite/deps/vue.js
```

(200):

```
https://dev.localhost/my-project-name/src/main.ts
```

Nginx error log example:

```
2022/11/07 16:40:56 [error] 49#49: *801 access forbidden by rule, client: [IP], server: dev.localhost, request: "GET /my-project-name/node_modules/.vite/deps/vue.js?v=cf1cc6c7 HTTP/1.1", host: "dev.localhost", referrer: "https://dev.localhost/my-project-name/src/main.ts"
```

Works fine on localhost, searched Vite/nginx for related issues but couldn't find anything.

TIA!

Comment: Use `nginx -T` (uppercase `T`) to view the entire Nginx configuration across all included files. It may be caused by a `deny all` statement - possibly within a location that matches any directory that begins with a `.`

Comment: @RichardSmith Thanks, that helped a ton. I was looking for "403" and wasn't escaping the `.` so obviously a million results were found.

Found this while looking for `deny all`, generated by nginxconfig.io.

`
# . files
location ~ /\.(?!well-known) {
    deny all;
}
`